# База данных h2 не сохраняет данные при перезапуске сервера

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-boot, h2

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# default path: h2-console
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-ui

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.initialize=false
```

При перезапуске сервера данные, введенные на http://localhost:8080/h2-ui не сохраняются
Что можно сделать?

Видела похожие вопросы, не помогли.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/filename

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Заработало! Вы меня спасли)) спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Так у тебя база данных в озу хранится.

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test
```

`mem` означает, что все данные в памяти хранятся.